# how to create a authorization header in apollo server with express middleware latest

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, authorization, apollo-server

I'd like to seek assistance on how to implement authorization in the Apollo server to restrict immediate access to the payload result. I've searched on Google and other dev forums, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you.

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
 import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    introspection: true,
    csrfPrevention: true,
    cache: "bounded",
    async onHealthCheck() {
        try {
          const healthInfo = {
            uptime: process.uptime(),
            memoryUsage: process.memoryUsage(),
            cpuUsage: process.cpuUsage(),
            nodeVersion: process.version,
            timestamp: new Date()
          };
          return healthInfo;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error('An error occurred while getting health info');
        }
      },
    plugins: [
        ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
        config.NODE_ENV === "PROD"
            ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
            : config.NODE_ENV === "STAGE"
            ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageProductionDefault({
                    graphRef: "my-graph-id@my-graph-variant",
                    footer: false,
              })
            : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ footer: false },   {embed : true}),
        // ApolloServerPluginInlineTrace({
        //     includeErrors: { transform: (err) => (err.message.match(SENSITIVE_REGEX) ? null : err) },
        // }),
    ],

});

const corsOptions = {
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};


const conditionalJwtCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (config.ENABLE_API_SECURITY) {
        jwtCheck(req, res, next);       
    } else {
        next();
    }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
app.use(
    "/graphql",
    //cors(corsOptions),
    json({ limit: config.PAYLOAD_LIMIT }), // Adjust limit based on your requirements
    express.json({ limit: config.PAYLOAD_LIMIT }), // Adjust limit based on your requirements
    speedLimiter,
    express.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
    conditionalJwtCheck,
    expressMiddleware(server, {
        context: async ({ req , res }) => {
            try {
            const token = req.headers.authorization || "";
            await auditProcessor.auditLogInput(req, res);
            
            return { token };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        }
        },
    })
);
```

I'd like to set a header for authorization first before accessing the mutations or queries.